# Objective-C: what design patterns are there to hook up a model with views that are selected from a property list?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to build a MVC app with Objective-C. It is supposed to be a questionnaire app. I have all the questions and multiple choice answers stored into a property list, because I have different of questionnaires that I want to be able to load with this app. The idea is that the main model will keep track which item it should read of the property list, and select the corresponding view and viewController.

So schematically I have the following problem.
[image]

**The RootView** shows the start menu, that selects which questionnaire you will be able to take.

**The RootViewController** is the first controller called by the app delegate. It is supposed to instantiate the model and show the RootView. It furthermore controls the buttons of the RootView.

**The model** is supposed to wrap the items of the property list into a fitting datastructure, and supply it to the view controllers that need it.

**The SelectedViewController** is a controller that is a template specifically made for a type of question. The question could be a multiple choice, an open question, a 3, 5 or 7 choice likert scale kind of question, anything really. The template name that these view controllers will really get is ViewController.

**The SelectedView** is a tailor made view to the question type and will get the same name format as all the selected view controllers.

Here are my ideas.

- My initial hunch is to use the delegate pattern, and set the model as a delegate to any SelectedViewController.
- I could also use the delegate pattern to the RootViewController, and let him monitor if the SelectedViewController should be destroyed (via a delegate message). In that case, I can implement a prepareForSegue in the RootViewController to the SelectedViewController.
- Since it is a questionnaire from a plist I could also add a prepare for segue to
  every selected viewcontroller, but that will probably be a problem,
  since there are at least 15 different ways of displaying the
  questions.

Apparently there is also something like Key-Value Observing, according [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010864/ios-cocoa-design-pattern-for-data-model-controller). So that's also something I could use.

I think there is a definite way to deal with this, because the design patterns in iOS are pretty wel described, so there should be a few options for this really (or only just one). At the moment I am leaning towards setting the RootViewController as a delegate to the SelectedViewController and let the RootViewController handle the model. In this way I am extending the RootViewController to also hold all common functionality that every SelectedViewController should have.

But I am really not sure if this is the way to go, because my knowledge on design patterns is limited. My question is: what is the right option to choice in this specific situation (e.g. views and view controllers selected via a .plist file)?

Comment: What do you mean by "generated views"? You do not mention generating anything in the question.

Comment: Thanks, that is still a typo. I mean views (and view controllers) that I created myself that are selected by reading an item of the property list. For example, a property in an Item could say: "4MCQuizQuestion" and then I know that I need to instantiate the 4MCQuizQuestionView and 4MCQuizQuestionViewController. That is why I call this a SelectedView and SelectedViewController. I'll change the title name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a specific pattern - you can deal with accessing an instance of a model object by name, i.e. in the same exact way that you deal with making a specific view and the view controller.

Let's say you are looking to connect the `QuizQuestionViewController4MC` and its `QuizQuestionView4MC` to their model. Let's assume that the model class is called `QuizQuestionModel4MC`, and that it needs to be configured with an object that you get from a key `@"4MC"` in the plist. Since your code learns the name of the model class only at runtime, you can create an instance using reflection:

```
NSDictionary *dataFromPlist = ... // Someone passes this to you
NSString *identifier = dataFromPlist[@"identifier"]; // Returns @"4MC"
NSString *ctrlName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"QuestionViewController%@", identifier];
NSString *modelClassName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"QuizQuestionModel%@", identifier];
id model = [[NSClassFromString(modelClassName) alloc] init];
// Configure the model with the data from plist
[model setPlistData:dataFromPlist];
// The model is ready to be used - give it to the view controller
MyBaseViewController *ctrl = [storyboard – instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:ctrlName];
// Give the view controller its model - now it is ready to be used
[ctrl setModel:model];
```

Note the class of the view controller - `MyBaseViewController`. This is not your root view controller, it's a base class for all your specific view controllers. It is this view controller that knows about a model, but it does not know the specific subclass in the model hierarchy. Each subclass of the view controller knows about its specific model subclass, so it can access the information from the model class directly, without going through selectors or KVP.

Of course it is up to the designer of the app to "wire up" correct view controllers to the correct models. In terms of the above example, `QuizQuestionViewController4MC` needs to know the structure of the `QuizQuestionModel4MC` in order to avoid sending unrecognized selectors to an incorrect class.

Comment: Let me paraphrase it, to see to what extent I understand it. So in essence what you propose is that I should keep my RootViewController and Model. They take care of the administration of reading the .plist file and keeping track which question we are, uploading stuff when the questionnaire is done, etc. Then, the RootViewController owns a QuestionViewController<question_type> which is subclassed from the MyBaseViewController. Does this also mean that I have a baseModel and a subclassed model?

Comment: @MelvinRoest Yes, that's basically right. As far as the common class for the model goes, it may be a good idea, because you could define the `setPlistData:` method there. Technically, that is optional, because Objective C will have no problem dispatching the method dynamically. But you would get better readability if you make a base class. It would be a good place for the common functionality, too - same goes for `MyBaseViewController` and the functionality common to your view controllers.